# Facebook connect for my PHP application

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to make my users to login through Facebook Connect on my PHP web application. Can you please post some resources for beginners.

Thanks.

Regards,
Mugil.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this tutorial on using the facebook PHP SDK: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/ and the official facebook documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web

Answer (score 0):

There's a copy and paste solution for the [Facebook login](http://toolkit.launchbit.com) button. It's driven by Javascript but there's also PHP code for your members-only pages. This is a solution if you're only doing login. The Facebook developer guides is a good place to look for other functionalities.